# Modify UITableViewCell from UIViewController with UITableView Outlet on iPhone

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview

Here is the situation,

I have UIViewController class with a UITableView outlet.  I would like to modify / style the cell.  I believe I can do this with UITableViewCells tableviewCellWithReuseIdentifier method.  Since my class is not a UITableViewController it doesn't have this method.  How can I use this method from the UIViewController class.

Also I know I can create a custom UITableViewCell class and instantiate it instead of a regular UITableViewCell class but is there anyway that I can do this in the UIViewController class?

Thanks,
Joe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A UITableViewController is essentially a UIViewController with a UITableView instance and the viewController itself set as the `delegate` and `dataSource` for the table (which implies that the viewController implements stubs for those delegate methods).

You can do it yourself by having your UIViewController implement the `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate` protocols. Then in the UIViewController's `loadView` (or `viewDidLoad`) method set the tableView instance's `dataSource` and `delegate` to `self`.

To return a custom cell, in your UIViewController implement the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method and return the custom cell.

Also, check out Matt Gallagher's post on ways to customize a table cell without having to subclass UITableViewCell: http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/easy-custom-uitableview-drawing.html